# How to BACK from second screen to first screen when device rotate 90 degree in android cardboard?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cardboard

I am trying to develop an sample cardboard app in android. **In that I am switching from First screen to Second screen, and i have done that successfully**.

But when i am trying to BACK from second screen to first screen i don't know how to do that. I have gone through some of the links but didn't get success.

**I want to go back to first screen from second screen when device get 90 degrees rotated as it is doing in most cardboard apps on play-store.**

Can any one guide me how can I achieve this kind of functionality? Tutorials, links, explanations, anything?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need two screens , you need to update the layout when you rotate your screen .use two xml layout for the same activity. you need to handle screen change in onConfigurationChanged method.here is a full explanation on how to achieve it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422431/Handling-screen-layout-changes-in-Android